# ElasticSearch NEST: Bulk-indexing operation does not make use of specified document IDs

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I currently use the [ElasticSearch NEST 7.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/introduction.html) library.

On the VM that hosts my ElasticSearch master node, I am running a web server which receives JSON data via REST. These JSON data are then to be saved inside ElasticSearch.

First, the received JSON data are passed into this method for parsing:

```
private static (bool Success, string ErrorMessage) TryReadRawJsonData(
    string rawJsonData, out IEnumerable<(string Index, ExpandoObject JsonContent)> jsonLines)
{
    var results = new List<(string Index, ExpandoObject JsonContent)>();

    foreach (string rawDataLine in HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(rawJsonData).Split('\n').Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)))
    {
        dynamic expandoObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(rawDataLine);

        if (!Dynamic.HasProperty(expandoObject, "IndexId"))
        {
            jsonLines = Enumerable.Empty<(string, ExpandoObject)>();
            return (Success: false, ErrorMessage: $"No field named 'IndexId' found in {rawDataLine}.");
        }

        string indexId = (string)expandoObject.IndexId.ToLower();
        results.Add((indexId, JsonContent: expandoObject));
    }

    jsonLines = results;
    return (Success: true, ErrorMessage: null);
}
```

If successfully parsed, the return value is subsequently passed into this method for bulk indexing:

```
private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> BulkIndexAsync(IEnumerable<(string Index, ExpandoObject JsonContent)> contents)
{
    foreach (var group in contents.GroupBy(line => line.Index))
    {
        BulkResponse bulkIndexResponse = 
            await ElasticClient.BulkAsync(bulk => bulk.Index(group.Key).IndexMany(group.Select(member => member.JsonContent)));

        if (bulkIndexResponse.Errors)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(bulkIndexResponse.ItemsWithErrors
                                                             .Select(itemWithError =>
                                                                 $"Index: {itemWithError.Index}; " +
                                                                 $"Document Id: {itemWithError.Id}; " +
                                                                 $"Error: {itemWithError.Error.Reason}.")
                                                             .ConcatenateIntoString(separator: "\n"))
            };
        }
    }
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

The bulk index operation succeeded, but the document IDs are unfortunately not as I expected. Here is an example:

```
{
    "_index": "dummyindex",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "U1W4Z20BcmiMRnw-blTi",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
        "IndexId": "dummyindex",
        "Id": "0c2d48bd-6842-4f15-b7f2-57fa259b0642",
        "UserId": "dummy_user_1",
        "Country": "dummy_stan"
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `Id` field is `0c2d48bd-6842-4f15-b7f2-57fa259b0642`, which, according to [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/ids-inference.html), should automatically be inferred as the document ID. However, the `_id` field is set to `U1W4Z20BcmiMRnw-blTi` instead of `0c2d48bd-6842-4f15-b7f2-57fa259b0642`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of elasticsearch do you use? Could you share sample bulk request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer taken from [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-nest-bulk-indexing-operation-does-not-make-use-of-specified-document-ids/201003/2?u=miao):**

The `Id` on an `ExpandoObject` is not a property of the type, but a key in the underlying `IDictionary<string,object>` that `ExpandoObject` is backed by.

You can see this by reflecting over the properties of `ExpandoObject` with

```
dynamic expandoObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(@"{
        ""IndexId"": ""dummyindex"",
        ""Id"": ""0c2d48bd-6842-4f15-b7f2-57fa259b0642"",
        ""UserId"": ""dummy_user_1"",
        ""Country"": ""dummy_stan""
    }
");

Type t = expandoObject.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    Console.WriteLine(property.ToString());
}
```

which prints

```
System.Dynamic.ExpandoClass Class
System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[System.String] System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<System.String,System.Object>.Keys
System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[System.Object] System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<System.String,System.Object>.Values
System.Object System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<System.String,System.Object>.Item [System.String]
Int32 System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.String,System.Object>>.Count
Boolean System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.String,System.Object>>.IsReadOnly
```

To solve your issue, you can specify the `Id` for each document however by passing the second delegate argument to `.IndexMany()`:

```
dynamic expandoObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(@"{
        ""IndexId"": ""dummyindex"",
        ""Id"": ""0c2d48bd-6842-4f15-b7f2-57fa259b0642"",
        ""UserId"": ""dummy_user_1"",
        ""Country"": ""dummy_stan""
    }
");

var bulkResponse = client.Bulk(bu => bu
    .IndexMany(new[] { expandoObject }, (b, d) => b.Id((Id)d.Id))
);
```

The cast of `d.Id` to `Id` (or could have been string as that is the actual type, but casting to `Id` will use the implicit conversion from string to `Id`) is required because `d` is a dynamic type and the runtime is unable to dispatch without it.